# Volume of a leaky tank

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> A tank of water is initially leaking at a rate of $1$ litre per minute. The rate it continues to leak at is proportional to the volume in the tank. After $7$ minutes, the tank is half full. What is the capacity of the tank?

I set $dV/dt=-kV$ where $V$ is volume and $k$ is constant.

Plugging in the initial conditions of $dV/dt(t=0)=-1$ tells me $k=V_{t=0}^{-1}$ and so I have $dV/dt=-V_{t=0}^{-1} V$. Now we integrate to get $\ln{V}=-V_{t=0}^{-1} t$ or $V=-e^{V^{-1}_{t=0}t}$.

Using $V(t=7)=\frac{1}{2} V_{t=0}^{-1}$, we find $\frac{1}{2} V_{t=0}^{-1} = -e^{7V_{t=0}^{-1}}$. Does this have any real solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the integration constant when solving the DE. The general solution to $\frac{dV}{dt}=-kV$ is $$V(t)=e^{-kt+c}=e^ce^{-kt}$$
where the constant $e^c=V_0$. You then have the equation $$\frac{1}{2}V_0=V_0 e^{-7/V_0}$$

Let me know if the path from here isn't clear, and I'll elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a constant of integration when you integrate. Moreover, when you say $\ln V=-ct$, you get $V=e^{-ct}$, not $V=-e^{ct}$.

Let the capacity be $V_0$.
$$\frac{dV}{dt}=-kV$$
$$[\ln V]_{V_0}^{V}=-k[t]_{0}^{t}$$
$$\ln\left(\frac{V}{V_0}\right)=-kt$$

Moreover, at $t=0$, $\frac{dV}{dt}=-1$ and $V=V_0$.
Thus,
$$-1=-kV_0$$
$$k=\frac{1}{V_0}$$

which gives,
$$\ln\left(\frac{V}{V_0}\right)=-\frac{1}{V_0}t$$

At $t=0$, $V=\frac{V_0}{2}$

Thus,
$$\ln\left(\frac{\frac{V_0}2}{V_0}\right)=-\frac{1}{V_0}7$$
$$\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=-\frac{1}{V_0}7$$
$$V_0=\frac{7}{\ln 2}$$
with appropriate units.

Regarding the other part of the question, it can be seen by drawing a graph that $\frac{x}{2}=-e^{7x}$ has a solution in the fourth quadrant. Clearly, if $x$ denoted the volume of the tank, then there would be no solution.

Comment: Hi thanks for this. Actually this was a mistake on my part when I re-did it today. I did it originally in a test a few days ago and got the same answer you have above and it was marked incorrect which got me puzzled. Oh well...

Comment: @user11128 There is one missing point - I assumed that the tank is initially full, but the question does not mention it anywhere.

Comment: Yes I think we are to assume this. Don't know what the problem was then.....alas